# Mercurial hook that operates like 'changegroup', but only on push?

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook, hgrc

We've built a changeset propagation mechanism, but it relies on bundling and unbundling the new changesets. If we were to use the `changegroup` hook, then it would cause cyclic behaviors, because the hook is run [during a pull, push, or unbundle](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook#The_changegroup_hook). What we need is for the sync to be done after a commit, which the `commit` hook works perfectly for, but also after a **push**.

Note, the `post-push` hook is not the answer, as it is run when you push *from* that repository to another. This scenario calls, basically, for a special behavior of `changegroup`, only running when the new changesets are a result of a push.

Is there any hook that works that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [source argument](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec%3ahook%3asources) to the hook. It will be `bundle` when you're unbundling a changegroup, `serve` when the changeset comes in over HTTP(S) or SSH, and `push` when it comes in via a push done to a repository on the local file system.

You find this argument as the `HG_SOURCE` environment variable for a hook run as an external process, and as the `source` keyword argument for an in-process hook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have, in fact, written a small Python script that does just that. The dilemma that I'm facing, however, is that our development team uses Windows systems, and I'm hesitant about insisting that we install Python on all servers. Could I write a `.bat` file or something that can run without external dependencies?

Comment: Upon further experimentation, it seems that TortoiseHG comes with Python embedded (duh), and runs hooks using its internal Python runtime - so you don't have to use  a .bat file.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here is a script that would work (as per @MartinGeisler's answer). Let's call it `pushhook.py`:

```
def pushhook(ui, repo, source=None, **kwargs):
    if source == 'push':
        # Perform push-only operations here
```

And the `hgrc` looks like:

```
[hooks]
changegroup.push = python:.hg/pushhook.py:pushhook
```