# Mercurial pretxncommit hook - act only on commit, ignore rebase and patch

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

We are using `pretxncommit` hook for HG to run a quick static analysis check on code commited. However the hook is triggered on applying any changes to commit tree - which includes rebasing and using MQ to edit and squash commits.

Is it possible to somehow check what type of change is happening in hook itself? Like

```
def analyze_hook(ui, repo, node=None, **kwargs):
    if repo.state.is_commit_added and not (repo.state.is_rebase or repo.state.is_patch):
        return 0
```

Comment: It is possible to `from mercurial.cmdutil import _getrepostate` and check `_getrepostate(repo) is not None` to check if the repo is _currently_ in process of rebase or graft. It prevents hook from acting on merge conflicts, but it still acts once rebase or graft or MQ move is finished.

Answer (score 0):

you'd want to check the HG_SOURCE to see what operation is bringing you those commits

https://book.mercurial-scm.org/read/hook.html#sources-of-changesets

e.g. https://github.com/vmg/hg-stable/blob/master/tests/test-hook.t

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105493/1681985